# How to connect to Windows Remote Desktop access via LAN over WireGuard?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, remote-desktop, wireguard

I have Wireguard VPN set up in a remote server, that I'd like to have clients connected to (macOS, Win or Linux).

There's a client, that serves as a host for Windows Remote Desktop! This is accessible by authenticated with a Username and Password by using a Windows Remote Desktop Client application that is available for Windows or MacOS.

I want to have any of the clients on the VPN be able to connect to the Windows Remote Desktop Host in the LAN.

So far my attempts failed with an error, here's an example of a MacOS Client trying to connect to the host Remote Desktop (both connected to Wireguard VPN):

[image]

Attempted a few things, such as, set the gateway to 0.0.0.0, as defined in the Wireguard conf file of the host and clients, but same issue (tried with or without bypassing for local addresses):

[image]

If I don't use the Wireguard VPN, for machines in the same LAN, I can find the Windows Remote Desktop and connect to it, without any issues.

Only when I connect to Wireguard VPN, is that I can't connect via Windows Remote Desktop.
Although, I can ping IP addresses in the same LAN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When connecting, the "computer name" is asked and instead of putting the name as text, added the IP address of the target machine Wireguard IP Address and it worked!